# Firebase Auth Check returning a user even when there (definitely) shouldn't be one

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm performing a check to see if there is a user session and creating an anonymous account if there isn't

This was working perfectly up until a few days ago but just before launch, we ran our final checks and now the user check returns a user ID even though there shouldn't be one.

App has been freshly installed, but usr is never nil - which is what I'd expect it to be. Each time we uninstall and reinstall, the user ID is exactly the same. No anonymous user is created in Firebase.

One other twist in the tale which might help diagnose. It works as expected on the simulator...and I've recently been working on setting up push notifications.

```
// Check if user is logged in, if not, create anonymous auth so users can access DB and storage w/o an account
    let checkAuth = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, usr in
        if usr == nil {

            // No user is signed in.
            Auth.auth().signInAnonymously() { (usr, err) in
                if (err == nil) {
                    let uid = usr!.uid
                    print("Anon User ID \(uid)")
                } else {
                    print("Anon auth error \(String(describing: err!.localizedDescription))")
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("User ID \(usr!.uid) and provider \(usr!.providerID)")
        }
    }

    Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(checkAuth)        
    return true
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase likely uses the keychain to store the user session. The keychain behaves differently on the simulator and device. Because it uses the keychain, the stored user session will survive app uninstall/reinstall.

A simple fix: use UserDefaults to store a flag that determines whether this is the first run of the app since it was installed. In your `AppDelegate`, consult the flag, `try? Auth.auth().signOut()` and update the flag.